# How to parse value from key in django template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

First i want to explain what i want to achieve.

at first this my query at view
`invoices = vendor.invoices.order_by('-due_date')`

this is the relevant model :

```
class Booking(model.Models):
    ...
    invoice = models.ForeignKey('invoices.Invoice', related_name="bookings", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                blank=True, null=True)
    POD_RETURN_STATUS = Choices(
        (1, 'on_driver', 'On Driver'),
        (2, 'taken_by_recipient', 'Taken by Recipient'),
        ...
    )
    pod_return_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=POD_RETURN_STATUS, blank=True, null=True)
```

whats new is i want to add the `pod_return_status` in template using `invoice` query. So like

```
{% for invoice in invoices %}
    ...
    <td>{{ invoice.bookings.first.pod_return_status }}</td>

{% endfor %}
```

but of course it increases the number of query. at first i use `prefetch_related` but it seems to added more query. So after consulting with chatGPT this is my updated_query:

```
invoices = vendor.invoices.order_by('-due_date').annotate(
        pod_return_status=Subquery(
            Booking.objects.filter(vendor_invoice=OuterRef('pk')).values('pod_return_status')[:1]
        )
    )
```

it looks good on query numbers, but when i want to parse in template like this `<td>{{ invoice.pod_return_status }}</td>` it display the number like 1,2. what i want to display is the value of it like, 'On Driver' etc.

Since im using model_utils.Choice, usually to display in template i use `booking.get_field_name_display`. but since the pod_return_status is acquired from annotation, not from the parents model. i cant use that.

what im trying is to parse `"POD_RETURN_STATUS": Booking.POD_RETURN_STATUS,` to context_data so i can parse it in template like `<td>{{ POD_RETURN_STATUS[invoice.pod_return_status] }}</td>` but it seems it cant acquired the value using that way. My question is about how can i yield that value in template, using Dict key to get value. But im open if there is another way to achieve that, like different query or smth. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `.prefetch_related` would have worked if you changed to access to be:

```
{% for invoice in invoices %}
    ...
    <td>{{ invoice.bookings.all.0.get_pod_return_status_display}}</td>

{% endfor %}
```

In a lot a cases `.first()` ignores the cache. That's probably the reason you still got a lot of queries.

Using a subquery will not work because it is neede to call `.values()` to limit the number of columns returned to one. This will get rid of the model layer losing the cability of linking `pod_return_status` to its display.

Alternatively you coul rebuild the link between choices values and display in the query.

```py
whens = [When(pod_return_status=value, then=label) for (value, label) in Booking.POD_RETURN_STATUS.choices]

booking_qs = Booking.objects.all()
booking_qs = booking_qs.annotate(pod_return_status_label=Case(*whens))

invoices = vendor.invoices.order_by('-due_date').annotate(
        pod_return_status=Subquery(
            booking_qs.filter(vendor_invoice=OuterRef('pk')).values('pod_return_status_label')[:1]
        )
    )
```